# Jupyter Notebook - How to use a data file for code

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter

this might seem like stupid question, but i don't know how to resolve this problem.

So i'm trying to integrate a code of mine that i made in ipython and make it look much much better documented. My code uses a numpy file that i made a path to use it for.

So my question is, how would i upload this numpy file to my notebook so I can use it in my .ipynb file? I tried having the .npy and .ipynb files in the same folder, but i'm clueless on how to call it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you created the file with "numpy.save" then you should be able to read it with "numpy.load" if it is in the same directory.

Here's an example:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]])

np.save("test", x)

y = np.load("test.npy")

print y
```

Comment: Sorry i'm new and a complete idiot when it comes to these things. I'm not creating  a new file. I already have existing file with data i want to use.

Comment: If your "filename.npy" file is in the same directory then `data = np.load("filename.npy")` should load it for you. This does not work for you?

Comment: No, but that is most likely because it is not in the same directory. I'll try to fix that and see.